# Como actualizar o PHP 7.0.0RC1 para a versão já lançada 7.0 no centOS?

Tags: centos, php-7

Bom dia,

Como faço para actualizar o PHP 7.0.0RC1 para a versão já lançada 7.0 no centOS?

Obrigado

Comment: Atualizar não sei como ainda, mas dá pra instalar. https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, no entanto eu tenho já instalada a versão 7 RC no entanto queria actualizar para esta versão final lançada ontem (3 de Dezembro 2015).

Comment: Alguma ideia de como desinstalar o PHP 7.0 RC1 do centOS

Comment: Também tentei. Não vi nenhum tutorial ensinando a instalar via `apt-get`. Se descobrir te falo

Comment: Ok obrigado, caso enontre publicarei aqui também!

Comment: Isso vai dar problemas se for esta a máquina que usas para trabalhar.

Comment: Referes-te ao centOS?

Comment: Não precisa duplicar a pergunta, era só ter traduzido a outra, presumindo que seja outra conta sua: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101956/3635

Comment: Malta, eu removi a directoria onde estava instalado o PHP 7.0 RC 1 e instalei a versão já lançada ontem, mas no entanto quando executo o phpinfo() aparece-me a dizer que ainda tenho a versão RC1

Comment: Sim era minha a conta e peço desculpa por não ter traduzido. Obrigado

Comment: Votei por deixar aberta a pergunta, pois me parece estar no limite do escopo, mas não fora. Só recomendo que de detalhes de como instalou a versão RC1 que pode ter sido o que "travou" a instalação final.

Comment: Para a instalação da versão RC1 segui estes passos:´

Comment: http://www.tecmint.com/install-and-compile-php-7-on-centos-7-and-debian-8/

Comment: Boa tarde malta, já resolvi o problema acabei agora de publicar a solução, esperando ajudar quem estiver com problemas semelhantes! Cumprimentos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar a versão do PHP 7 RC e instalar a versão final lançada no dia 3 de Dezembro (Versão 7.0.0) terão de executar os seguintes passos:

**1 Passo:** 
Desinstalar manualmente a pasta e os conteúdos presentesem  php-7.0.0RC1

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -rf php-7.0.0RC1
```

**2 Passo:** Desinstalar o libphp7.so presente na directoria *"modules"*

```
cd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/
sudo rm -rf libphp7.so
```

**3 Passo:** Fazer o download do PHP 7.0.0 Realased lançado no dia 3 de Dezembro a partir da página oficial do php- php.net

```
sudo wget http://php.net/get/php-7.0.0.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
```

**4 Passo:** Extrair os ficheitros do arquivo baixado *tar.bz2 para a directoria /opt

```
tar xzf php-7.0.0RC1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

**5 Passo:** Feito isto, na directoria /opt/php-7.0.0 executa-se o buildconf -force, fazendo:

```
cd /opt/php-7.0.0
ls
./buildconf --force
```

**6 Passo:** Executa-se em seguida o comando ./configure. Em baixo segue-se a instrução para executar uma instalação típica do php, no entanto para uma instalação personalizada podem sempre ver os manuais do php, em php.net.

```
    ./configure \
--prefix=$HOME/php7/usr \
--with-config-file-path=$HOME/php7/usr/etc \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-zip \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-exif \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
--enable-wddx \
--with-curl \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-iconv \
--with-gmp \
--with-pspell \
--with-gd \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
--with-png-dir=/usr \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr \
--with-xpm-dir=/usr \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--with-openssl \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr \
--with-gettext=/usr \
--with-zlib=/usr \
--with-bz2=/usr \
--with-recode=/usr \
--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
--with-apxs2
```

**7 Passo:** Feito isto, devem executar estes comandos:

```
make
```

em seguida executem:

```
make install
```

**8 Passo:** Façam restart ao servidor apache

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

**9 Passo:** Concluído! Podem agora executar o ***phpinfo()*** para verificarem se a instalação foi bem sucedida, verificando se a versão agora iinstalada é a 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Caso possua o YUM, recomendo o repositório [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/)

Antes de instalar qualquer coisa, sempre verifique se já não existe outras instalação.

> yum list installed | grep **php** | cut -d' ' -f1

Em negrito,  palavra chave para buscar. Nesse caso, estamos procurando por instalações relacionadas ao PHP.

Se necessário, remova o que encontrar. Exemplo:

```
>yum remove php5-antigo
```

O nome do pacote (package) deve ser exatamente igual ao que aparece na lista da busca realizada anteriormente.

Caso queira remover tudo, basta fazer:

```
>yum remove php5*
```

Após confirmar que está tudo limpo e sem riscos de conflitos, prosseguimos com a instalação.

**Atualiza o repositório:**

```
>rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
>rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

**Instala o PHP**

```
>yum install php70w
```

Está feito!

**Para adicionar extensões**

```
>yum install php70w-nome_da_extensão
```

Exemplo instalando PHP-BCMath:

```
>yum install php70w-bcmath
```

**Após completar, confira no console**

```
>php -v
```

Mostrará a versão

```
>php -m
```

Mostrará as extensões carregadas