# Como instalar o PHP7 no *unix

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7

Resolvi testar um sistema unix-like (Linux Mint) para aprender mais, e eu preciso instalar o PHP7, porque o [PHPtherightway](http://br.phptherightway.com/) mandou. Já instalei o apache2 via Terminal e o Mysql. Sei que tem um jeito de instalar o PHP7 via terminal, mas segundo esse cara [aqui](https://askubuntu.com/a/706559/505439), ainda não tem uma release oficial. Então eu fui la no http://php.net/ e baixei este pacote aqui [PHP7](http://php.net/get/php-7.0.3.tar.gz/from/a/mirror). Lá tem um arquivo `install`, eu li, mas não entendi como se instala um pacote desses via terminal. alguém com experiência com isto poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como actualizar o PHP 7.0.0RC1 para a versão já lançada 7.0 no centOS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101971/91) e
[Após comando “apt-get dist-upgrade” foi instalado o PHP 7. Como voltar para o 5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106632/91)

Answer (score 1):

No terminal do Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-gd
```

OBS.: O código acima vai instalar o PHP FPM, ideal para nginx ou Apache worker. Caso esteja usando o Apache prefork + mod_php, use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-gd
```

Já inclui as bibliotecas cURL, MySQL, Mcrypt e GD. Tem uma explicação mais detalhada nesse link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: No meu caso deu o erro Impossível encontrar o pacote php7.0, sabe o que pode ser? Uso Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @fernandoandrade tem certeza que você adicionou o repositório e depois deu um `update`?

Comment: Sim @Gabriel S.  ele aparece com o $ apt-cache policy
500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ vivid/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ vivid/main i386 Packages
     release v=15.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=vivid,n=vivid,l=PPA for co-installable PHP 5.6 + 7.0,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net

Comment: @fernandoandrade Segundo essa resposta (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35766715/1161005), parece que os pacotes do PHP foram removidos do repositório ppa:ondrej/php para a versão 15.04 do Ubuntu. Atualizar para a versão 15.10 deveria resolver esse problema (Mas eu recomendo atualizar logo para a versão 16.04 com uma instalação limpa)

Comment: Verdade, melhor atualizar. Vlw @Gabriel S.